# SpecFlow / BDD Examples

Tags: bdd, specflow

Just looking for some examples of `BDD/SpecFlow` - ideally a projectб so I can see how to use `SpecFlow` on big projects where multiple features my reference the same steps etc.

I've read a few blogs over the last few months, but haven't had a nice, juicy project of someone else's to mooch around through.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The official example set of [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) can be found on github: http://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples

The ASP.NET-MVC/BookShop sample is the one that you can have a look. It is not a very big project though. (If you a need VS2010 sample, switch to the VS2010 branch.)

Answer (score 12):

Another great place to find examples are from the tests for the SpecFlow project itself.

In particular those used to test the Gherkin parsing: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/tree/master/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs/Features

Those tests show a lot of ways to write scenarios using syntax for mutliline parameters, table parameters, templates, and more.

Comment: isn't that what Gaspar said 6 months ago (see above)? :P :)

Comment: No, Gasper linked to the examples provided with SpecFlow. Those examples don't show every bit of Gherkin (or SpecFlow specific) syntax it can handle.

I linked to the feature tests for SpecFlow itself (which are written as .feature files). These show a lot more than the basic examples.

Answer (score 8):

Also check out Steve Sanderson's [GuestbookDemo](http://github.com/SteveSanderson/GuestbookDemo), which shows off how to use SpecFlow with [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 6):

Also, see Brandon Satrom's recent MSDN article on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We have used SpecFlow to formulate scenarios on the [CQRS Journey](http://aka.ms/cqrs) project. Check out the [overview](http://cqrsjourney.github.com/blog/2012/05/14/Specing-Out-End-To-End-Scenarios/) of how we did it and then take a look at the acceptance tests themselves in the code repo.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an answered question. Just in case some one needs a quick simple web test project skeleton. I have created a nuget package SeleniumNUnitSpecflow for quickly setting up Specflow with Nunit and Selenium.

PM> Install-Package SeleniumNUnitSpecflow

Details: [Web page BDD test with selenium specflow nunit](http://codelife.cybtamin.com/web-page-bdd-test-with-selenium-specflow-nunit/)